# Синтаксис дочернего vue компонента

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, компоненты, связывание-данных

Смотрю видеурок [Vue 3 фундаментальный курс от А до Я](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzLuMtDelGk) с 1:25:00-1:28:30. Там сказано, что в объявлении дочернего компонента my-select нужно

MySelect.vue

```
<template>
  <select v-model="modelValue" @change="changeOption">
    <option disabled value="">Выберите из списка</option>
    <option
      v-for="option in options"
      :key="option.value"
      :value="option.value"
    >
      {{ option.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-select',
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeOption(event) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

а в родительском

PostForm.vue

```
<my-select
    v-model="selectedSort"
/>
```

Аналогично двустороннее связывание реализовывалось с 58:00-1:02:00.

PostForm.vue

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent>
    <h4>Создание поста</h4>
    <my-input
      v-focus
      v-model="post.title"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Название"
    />
    <my-input
      v-model="post.body"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Описание"
    />
    <my-button
      style="align-self: flex-end; margin-top: 15px"
      @click="createPost"
    >
      Создать
    </my-button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      post: {
        title: '',
        body: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createPost() {
      this.post.id = Date.now();
      this.$emit('create', this.post)
      this.post = {
        title: '',
        body: ''
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

</style>
```

MyInput.vue

```
<template>
  <input :value="modelValue" @input="updateInput" class="input" type="text">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-input',
  props: {
    modelValue: [String, Number]
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid teal;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

</style>
```

В связи с этим (см. с 58:00-1:02:00) соответственно в my-select должно быть

```
<select :value="modelValue" @change="changeOption">
```

вместо

```
<select v-model="modelValue" @change="changeOption">
```

Правильный ли я вывод сделал?

Comment: Изучайте сразу самое лучшее в Vue3 - Composition API - тогда можно все сделать удобнее.
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html
Если интересно  - у меня сделан универсальный Select (для Массива и Объекта)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1526359/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-select-%d0%bd%d0%b0-vue-3-composition-api/1526360#1526360