Клик вне элемента div
Есть кастомный select, двух видов, с выбором одного значения и нескольких. Отслеживаю клик вне элемента с помощью @focusout. Проблема в том что, при попытке выбрать значение в элементе с одинарным выбором, она сразу закрывается, срабатывает @focusout и значение переопределяется через раз. При этом в элементе с мульти значением, все работает отлично.
Код на play.vuejs.org
Может есть какие-то другие альтернативы, как реализовать закрытие при клике вне элемента?
upd.
Понял что баг происходит, если кликать на input, если вне инпута, а у самых границ элемента, то все окей

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1526359/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-select-%d0%bd%d0%b0-vue-3-composition-api

@Михаил а сможете помочь конкретно с моим кодом? Просто я не до конца понял, как работает ваш

Попробуйте для мультиселекта  поставить <div class="custom-select-body" :class="active ? 'active' : ''"  @mouseout="dropdownController()">
Просто я уже давно использую CompositionApi - по честному - нет времени все сначала разбирать. А мой Селект написан для случая Табов - много однотипных селектов.

И кстати у вас когда в мультиселекте выбираются/убираются опции не последовательно расположению - то необходимо "приводить" выбранный массив к образцовому порядку, какой вы задаете в Options. Для этого просто после каждого "выбора"/изменения массива выбранных делайте:
Выбранный = Опции.filter(e => выбранный.includes(e))
И порядок следования в выбранном массиве всегда будет как задаете в Options.

Способ с @mouseout не подходит

Поставьте <div class="custom-select-body" :class="active ? 'active' : ''" @mouseout="dropdownController()">
ТОЛЬКО в строке 22 на play.vuejs.org - и все как и просили))) - закрытие Мульти при клике ВНЕ селекта - остальное тоже.

@mouseout срабатывает когда указатель покидает div, а не обрабатывает клик вне div

Вот "заставили"))) еще раз вернуться к своему Селекту! Как результат - упростил и модифицировал с полезной фичей - отслеживание событий на элементах Root Div по любому присвоенному имени). Фактически @click на Root Div и есть отслеживатель событий - так что не нужно дополнительно Listeners или Directives.
Если любопытно - можете глянуть - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1526359/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-select-%d0%bd%d0%b0-vue-3-composition-api
Поставил Новый себе на Админку уже)))

Нашел решение данному вопросу.
В основной JS файл нужно добавить директиву
const clickOutside = {
beforeMount: (el, binding) => {
    el.clickOutsideEvent = event => {
        // here I check that click was outside the el and his children
        if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
            // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
            binding.value();
        }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
},
unmounted: el => {
    document.removeEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
},};

createApp(App)
  .directive("click-outside", clickOutside)
  .mount("#app");

К компоненту (div)
<div class="custom-select" v-click-outside="someFunction()"></div>

